# How to add 'new docx' item in Ubuntu file manager context menu?

Tags: 13.10, libreoffice, filemanager

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with it's default 'Files' file manager. It's really annoying to have to save every newly created documents to manually specified location in Libre writer every time. So, is there any way to add new entry to the file manager context menu so that I can create empty docx file by one click.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to add a document to ~/Templates (the Templates folder in your home directory).  For example, if you put stuff.docx in this folder, under the "new document" option in the context menu, "stuff" will be an entry and will create a docx document when clicked.  This actually creates a copy of the file in the "Templates" folder so you can put text into the document and it will be copied into every document created from this menu.

This can be used to add any document type you wish to the "New Document" right-click option.